# dc.js filtering on multi-criteria dimension

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I can't figure out how to get the following filter on column A working, in case multiple columns are used for a dimension in dc.js:

```
 var Dimension = dim.dimension(function(d) {
     return [d.columnA, d.columnB, d.columnC];
 });

 var Measure = Dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
     return d.columnD;
 });
 Dimension.filter("Value_in_columnA");
```

In case only a single column is used in the dimension, a filter works fine as follows:

```
 var Dimension = dim.dimension(function(d) {
     return d.columnA;
 });

 var Measure = Dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { 
     return d.columnB;
 }); 
 Dimension.filter("Value_in_columnA");
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, solution is as follows:

```
var Dimension = dim.dimension(function(d) {
   return [d.columnA, d.columnB, d.columnC];
});

var Measure = Dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    if (d.columnA === 'Value_in_columnA') {
        return d.columnD;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```